# bot accepting user input via DM?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Testing out moving some of my setup modules to DMs instead of in a server channel, as if I do it in a channel, people can easily get a bit confused with responses even though I have the bot set to ignore anyone but the original command author

I've tried the usual `wait_for` handler, but I can't seem to get the bot to catch the input via dm

```
@commands.command(name="dmstats")
async def stat_dm(self, ctx):
    member = ctx.author
    stat_list = await self.get_stat_vals(ctx, member)
    reply = await ctx.author.send("What value do you want?")
    await self.bot.wait_for('message')
    if reply.content.lower() == "strength":
        await ctx.author.send("Your strength is: {}".format(stat_list["strength"]))
```

Expected that when I `[p]dmstats` and trigger the command, the bot will DM me and prompt me, which it does, however its not catching my response

Comment: I just read over that code snippet and saw something that might be the mistake

Comment: yep. wasn't working because I'm a doofus and assigned `reply` to the wrong `await`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only accept messages from that user in a DM channel, you can record the channel that you sent the message to the user in, and then apss that as part of a check to `wait_for`

```
@commands.command(name="dmstats")
async def stat_dm(self, ctx):
    stat_list = await self.get_stat_vals(ctx, member)
    msg = await ctx.author.send("What value do you want?")
    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == msg.channel
    reply = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
    if reply.content.lower() == "strength":
        await ctx.author.send("Your strength is: {}".format(stat_list["strength"]))
```